# Hyperref, target name without .1

Tags: hyperref

Can `hyperref` make anchors with arbitrary name? After `\currentpdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toc} \tableofcontents` I got PDF that can be linked like http://some.where/filename.pdf#nameddest=toc.1. However, ".1" feels unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cite the `hyperref` manual: "As name for the internal anchor `name` is used (in conjunction with `level`)." So the `.1` is the level of the bookmark. Reading through the source of `hyperref` and `bookmark` this behaviour is hard coded.

In principle you could get rid of the level in the label with

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\pdfbookmark[3][0]{%
  \Hy@writebookmark{}{#2}{#3}{#1}{toc}%
  \hyper@anchorstart{#3}\hyper@anchorend
}
\makeatother
```

but I doubt this is a good idea.